# How to hot-link style a Telerik RadGridView column?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, radgridview

How might might I style a `Telerik` `RadGridView` column in WPF to mimic hot-tracking? I'm looking for the column to normally appear like text but become underlined and change color when the mouse cursor hovers over the cell.